# Add projection to rioxarray dataset in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I've downloaded a netcdf from the Climate Data Store and would like to write a CRS to it, so I can clip it for a shapefile. However, I get an error when assigning a CRS.
Below my script and what is being printed. I receive this error after trying to write a crs:

MissingSpatialDimensionError: y dimension (lat) not found. Data variable: lon_bnds

```
# load netcdf with xarray
dset = xr.open_dataset(netcdf_fn)
print(dset)

# add projection system to nc
dset = dset.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace=True)

# mask CMIP6 data with shapefile
dset_shp = dset.rio.clip(shp.geometry.apply(mapping), shp.crs)

dset
Out[44]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (time: 1825, bnds: 2, lat: 2, lon: 1)
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) object 2021-01-01 12:00:00 ... 2025-12-31 12:00:00
  * lat          (lat) float64 0.4712 1.414
  * lon          (lon) float64 31.25
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    time_bnds    (time, bnds) object ...
    lat_bnds     (lat, bnds) float64 0.0 0.9424 0.9424 1.885
    lon_bnds     (lon, bnds) float64 ...
    pr           (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes: (12/48)
    Conventions:            CF-1.7 CMIP-6.2
    activity_id:            ScenarioMIP
    branch_method:          standard
    branch_time_in_child:   60225.0
    branch_time_in_parent:  60225.0
    comment:                none
                    ...
    title:                  CMCC-ESM2 output prepared for CMIP6
    variable_id:            pr
    variant_label:          r1i1p1f1
    license:                CMIP6 model data produced by CMCC is licensed und...
    cmor_version:           3.6.0
    tracking_id:            hdl:21.14100/0c6732f7-2cdd-4296-99a0-7952b7ca911e
```

Comment: Try moving the bounds coordinates into the cords first with set_coords

Comment: Any clue how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you call the rioxarray accessor [`ds.rio.clip`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_dataset.RasterDataset.clip) using a `xr.Dataset` rather than a `xr.DataArray`, rioxarray needs to guess which variables in the dataset should be clipped. The method docstring gives the following warning:

> Warning:
>
> Clips variables that have dimensions ‘x’/’y’. Others are appended as is.

So the issue you're running into is that rioxarray sees four variables in your dataset:

```py
Data variables:
    time_bnds    (time, bnds) object ...
    lat_bnds     (lat, bnds) float64 0.0 0.9424 0.9424 1.885
    lon_bnds     (lon, bnds) float64 ...
    pr           (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
```

Of these, `lat_bnds`, `lon_bnds`, and `pr` all have `x` *or* `y` dimensions which could conceivably be clipped. Rather than making some arbitrary choice about what to do in this situation, rioxarray is raising an error with the message `MissingSpatialDimensionError: y dimension (lat) not found. Data variable: lon_bnds`. This indicates that when processing the variable `lon_bnds`, it's not sure what to do, because it can find an `x` dimension but not a `y` dimension.

To address this, you have two options. The first is to call `clip` on the `pr` array only. This is probably the right call - generally I'd recommend only doing data processing with Arrays (not Datasets) whenever possible unless you *really* know you want to map an operation across all variables in the dataset. Calling clip on `pr` would look like this:

```py
clipped = dset.pr.rio.clip(shp.geometry.apply(mapping), shp.crs)
```

Alternatively, you could resolve the issue of having data_variables that really should be coordinates. You can use the method [`set_coords`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.set_coords.html)to reclassify the non-data `data_variables` as non-dimension `coordinates`. In this case:

```py
dset  = dset.set_coords(['time_bnds', 'lat_bnds', 'lon_bnds'])
```

I'm not sure if this will completely resolve your issue - it's possible that rioxarray will still raise this error when processing coordinates. You could always drop the bounds, too. But the first method of only calling this on a single variable will work.